# Create image (TIFF/PNG) from geodetic (lat/long) data

Tags: java, geotools, image, software-recommendations

Using Java, I need to render a bunch of geodetic data to an image, ideally TIFF or PNG. Specifically this is weather data, with each sample having a latitude, longitude, and amplitude value.

I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheeling by converting polar coordinates (lat, long) to Cartesian coordinates (x, y in `BufferedImage` or `Graphics2D`). Furthermore the amplitude value needs to rendered as a color gradient. I've looks at GeoTools and NASA's World Wind, but it's unclear and not obvious if it has this capability.

Is there a Java library that can do this?

Comment: What format is you data in currently?

Comment: Geotools is definitely your friend here. But the way to do this depends a lot on the type of data. Are those on a regular grid or would need to be interpolated?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using GDAL? Extensive information, Documentation and examples are available [on the Geographical Data Abstraction Library](http://www.gdal.org/index.html). You can get step-by-step help to compile the GDAL.jar library as described [here](http://geoexamples.blogspot.fr/2012/05/running-gdal-java.html)

gdal.ReprojectImage(src_ds, dst_ds) from from GDAL Class seems to be what you are looking for though I have never used it yet.